# unable to select element with xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, rss, atom-feed

I must be missing something here, but I am unable to figure it out.

I am using SimpleXML to parse a RSS and ATOM feed, but the problem is, using the same xpath method, I am not able to select `<link>` from ATOM feed while it's working with RSS feed.

Samples from both feed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    >

<channel>
    <title>比特客栈的文艺复兴</title>
    <atom:link href="http://bitinn.net/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link>http://bitinn.net</link>
    <description>We don&#039;t choose who we are, but we do choose who we become.</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Sun, 27 Apr 2014 14:43:22 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <language>en-US</language>
        <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
...


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
    xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0" xml:lang="en-US" xml:base="http://bitinn.net/wp-atom.php">
    <title type="text">比特客栈的文艺复兴</title>
    <subtitle type="text">We don't choose who we are, but we do choose who we become.</subtitle>
    <updated>2014-04-27T14:43:22Z</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://bitinn.net"/>
    <id>http://bitinn.net/feed/atom/</id>
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://bitinn.net/feed/atom/"/>
    <generator uri="http://wordpress.org/" version="3.9">WordPress</generator>
    <link rel="hub" href="http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com"/>
    <link rel="hub" href="http://superfeedr.com/hubbub"/>
    <entry>
        <author>
            <name>店长</name>
            <uri>http://bitinn.net/</uri>
        </author>
...
```

it seems `$xml->channel->xpath('atom:link[@rel="self"]');` works with RSS feed, but `$xml->xpath('link[@rel="self"]');` doesn't work with the ATOM feed. I suspect I am messing up namespace in the second query, but didn't find the right xpath query.

Anyone had an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since XPath 1.0 spec doesn't support default namespace (and since PHP SimpleXML use libxml, which as far as I know, implements 1.0 spec), we need to register the default namespace first for xpath to work properly.

So `$xml->registerXPathNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom')` first, then we can do `$xml->xpath('atom:link[@rel="self"]');` successfully.

Answer (score 2):

In the second case, a default `xmlns` is set at the `feed` root element, viz

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"  ...
```

Means that feed, and nested elements are now in `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`. You will need to adjust your xpath to accomodate this.

The xpath would be

```
atom:feed/atom:link[@rel="self"]
```

Where `xmlns:atom = 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'`

Comment: it makes sense, but i wonder why `<title>` is not affected by this default namespace, ie. `$xml->xpath('title')` seems to work with the ATOM feed.

Comment: What you can also do if you really get stuck is use namespace agnostic abilities like `->xpath('*[local-name()="link" and @rel="self"]')`

Comment: Please don't do that, it looks horribly. Please use the wildcard operator instead to avoid namespaces, i.e. `*:link`. By the way, your `<title/>` element is definitely in the atom namespace, so if you are truly accessing it using no namespaces at all, it is a bug in the implementation to return you the title element.

Comment: Unlike CSS here is no default namespace in Xpath 1.0. You always have to register your own prefixes. PHP has a bug and registers the namespace prefixes of the current context. Do NOT rely on that automatic namespace registration. Just register your own prefixes for Xpath expressions.

Comment: @dirkk @ThW thx for clearing that up. it was my mistake to confuse `$xml->title` with `$xml->xpath('title')`; it indeed needs `$xml->xpath('atom:title')` to query properly (after registering the `atom` namepspace)

Comment: Also I should note that this answer doesn't work with PHP xpath without registering the `atom` namespace, and you shouldn't use `atom:feed` as it's redundant.